# Trying to play video

Tags: qt

I am attempting to play a video file using the QMedia player.  Here is my code.  It does pop up a new window but the file does not play.  The variable video is a QString holding the relative path to the file in this case it would be "videos/wildlife.wmv".  What am I doing wrong?

```
    QMediaPlayer* player = new QMediaPlayer(this);
    QMediaPlaylist* list = new QMediaPlaylist();
    QVideoWidget *vw = new QVideoWidget();
    list->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(video));
    player->setVolume(100);
    player->setPlaylist(list);
    player->setVideoOutput(vw);
    vw->show();
    list->setCurrentIndex(0);
    player->play();
```

I noticed in the Application output window I get this following message:
    setGeometry: Unable to set geometry 0x0+480+190 on QWidgetWindow/'QVideoWidgetClassWindow'. Resulting geometry:  116x0+480+190 (frame: 8, 30, 8, 8, custom margin: 0, 0, 0, 0, minimum size: 0x0, maximum size: 16777215x16777215).

Thanks.
Bear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused by wrong path to file(when your file did not load, then player has nothing to show). You will get same error when you for example set unexisting pixmap to label.

Try:

Set full path to your file and check is it normal now.

Use `QFile::exists()` to be sure that your file(relative path) exists.

When I tried your code on my computer (MOV file format) I got same error and I didn't see video, but I heard voice. How did I fixe it on my computer? Try at least next, maybe it helps:

I resize `QVideoWidget` programmatically. For example:

```
//your code
player->setVideoOutput(vw);
vw->show();
vw->resize(1000,600);//Add this line
list->setCurrentIndex(0);
player->play();
```

Comment: I tried setting the full path with the same result.  I did the check on the relative path and it does exist.

Comment: @Bear35645 see my edit please. I tried your code on my computer and maybe found solution. Can you see video now?

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign playlist to player:

```
player->setPlaylist(list);
```

Also start from the beginning of the list:

```
list->setCurrentIndex(0);
```

Comment: thanks.  I made the changes you suggested and updated my original post to match my current code.  Unfortunately I am still getting the same results.

Comment: What is the error? Connect to `QMediaPlayer::error()` signal.

Comment: I peppered the code with if statements checking if player->error was not equal to QMediaPlayer::NoError.  No error seems to occur.  If I wanted to use a try/catch what would I put in as the catch parameter?